# Lifetime Compiler notations: '1 vs '2

Tags: rust

In the following Rust compiler error, the only difference between the expected type and the found type is that there are two lifetimes, `'1` and `'2`, expected, and in the found type they are the same, `'1` and `'1`. What is the compiler trying to assert? If two lifetimes must be the same by implementation, can't the compiler accept that `'1` is `'2`.

```rust
`impl` item signature doesn't match `trait` item signature
expected signature `fn(&'1 ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>) -> std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'2, f64, Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&'cellref f64) -> &'cellref CellValue<'cell>>`
   found signature `fn(&'1 ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>) -> std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'1, f64, Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&'cellref f64) -> &'cellref CellValue<'cell>>`
```

What is the compiler trying to tell you?

Comment: Please add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand the code that causes the error.

Comment: Hey @MacO'Brien. My concern is to stop treating Rust as a magical compiler binary that needs to be prodded and examined experimentally, and start treating it like a real language, like Lisp, that can be reasoned about independent of poking at a magical compiler. So I'm focused on trying to semantically understand the plain text of the error message, on its face, rather than diving down and having someone say, "Oh, it's caused by this", without explaining exactly how they got there.

Comment: The reason the code doesn't work could be determined from reading the code itself, even without the compiler error. We can't reason about the code "independent of poking at a magical compiler" if the only output you provide is from said compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a portion of an error message. Usually the rest of the error has annotations that explain what it means by `'1` and `'2`.

In any case, the compiler *expects* your `fn` type to return an object with the lifetime `'2` but you're giving it an object with a lifetime `'1` (which was the reference that was passed in). Usually this means that `'2` is a *longer* lifetime than `'1` though it can also mean they are completely unrelated lifetimes or potentially that `'1` *could* live long enough but its used in a type that considers it invariant and thus the compiler is not allowed to satisfy `'2`.

So, whatever you're passing this `fn` type to is expecting that function to return a `Iter` with a longer lifetime (or at least different lifetime) than you are - that being from the input reference.